# SQL - Server + Entitiy Framework orderby<datetime>

Tags: entity-framework

I want to order my projects by the last generated timestamp:

```
var projectsOrderd  = projects.OrderBy(r => r.Timestamps.Select(t => t.End));
```

but there is an error:
"DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable"

type of End: datetime

is there any solution?

ps: runnig the statment on the SQL-Server works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant sort by a collection (EG a .Select())

Perhaps you want something like

```
var projectsOrderd  = projects.OrderBy(r => r.Timestamps.Max(t => t.End));
```

or

```
var projectsOrderd  = projects.OrderBy(r => r.Timestamps.FirstOrDefault(t => t.End));
```